# How can I display an error which prevents the OpenFileDialog class from closing in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I am creating a basic drawing program in which the user can open projects by clicking on a certain .png file in the class. I am using the System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog class.
How can I make it so the Dialog shows an error, without closing, if the user tries to open the wrong file? 
For example: I want the user to click on the file "name.png" but the user clicks on a file named "picture.png". Now an error shows up asking the user to find the "name.png" and doesn't close the dialog.

Here is my code:

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "*.png Files|*.png|All files|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (openFileDialog.FileName.EndsWith(".png"))
            {
                if(openFileDialog.FileName.Equals("name.png"))
                {
                    //name.png found
                }
                else
                {
                    // it was the wrong file!    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I want the user to click on the file "name.png"" - then why are you giving them a choice in the first place. Makes no sense.

Comment: This smells like an assignment question that's asking you to put in a loop with an exit condition.

Comment: I want the choice because I am trying to create projects defined by their png file on the first level. From there I can find the rest of the locations of the project. Does that make better sense? I don't know if I said that well. And also this is not an assignment, though i'm not sure how I can use a loop here.

Comment: What framework are you using C# with WinForms? WPF? Something else? Why does a simple `MessageBox.Show(...)` not work?

Comment: Why not use `name.png` as a filter, instead of `*.png`?

Comment: @minitech Yeah, lzcd beat you to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking the results afterwards, set the filter to be `Name file|name.png`.

This way, the user is only able to select the file you desire, and there's no need for the additional checks.

Comment: Not exactly -- the user could still type the full path to some wrong file.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! @debracey the idea is that there could be many different projects defined by their first level png file with the specific name.

Comment: Was wondering when we'd hear from you. Good to see aboard!

Comment: @debracey Or simply type `*.*` as the filename to show all files and select any that way.